# ESCPOS image mode vs cut paper

Tags: java, escpos

Sorry if this will be treated as a dublicate to my previous question, but... 
I'm trying to send a printer using ESCPOS commands to write a image line, which is followed by a cut paper(partial cut) command, and in result i recieve the image line missing(at this point i tried two diffirent printers, one of which randomly skips the image line, and the other does that statically).

The whole image print scenario was taken from [new-grumpy-mentat](http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html),
with a minor alteration:

```
                for (int y = 0; y < image.length; y += 24) {
//This part
                    if (n == 2) {
                        bos.write(printerSchema.getCutPaper());
                    }
// END
                        bos.write(printerSchema.getImageMode());
                        // Set nL and nH based on the width of the image
                        bos.write(new byte[] { (byte) (0x00ff & image[y].length), (byte) ((0xff00 & image[y].length) >> 8) });
                        for (int x = 0; x < image[y].length; x++) {
                            // for each stripe, recollect 3 bytes (3 bytes = 24 bits)
                            bos.write(recollectSlice(y, x, image));
                        }

                    // Do a line feed, if not the printing will resume on the same
                    // line
                    bos.write(printerSchema.getLineFeed());
                    n++;
                }
```

I think that there must be something like a finalization operation for the image line to be drawn before the cut operation may proceed, but cant find anything on that.
Commands:

```
IMAGE_MODE = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x2A, 33 }, 
LINE_FEED = new byte[] { 0x0A },
LINE_SPACE_24 = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x33, 24 }, 
LINE_SPACE_30 = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x33, 30 },
CUT_PAPER = new byte[] { 29, 86, 1 };
```

Comment: I just checked with our own code that definitely works.  We use the exact same sequence, i.e. set image mode, set width of image, send image data, send line feed.  We observed, however, that for some printers we needed page mode.

Comment: But can you try to set the "cut after line N alteration" to test it out? Thing is, that i tried today on a new XPrinter Xp-80(dont even know what that is), and i recieved a 10 out of 10 image line backfire, but on the previous one (Sam4S Giant100 duplicate) i can recieve 100 good results and a few bad ones. From that i assumed that the image line draw must have some finishing pointer to draw the line before proceeding to the next command(cutline).

Comment: The line feed (0x0a) is that "finishing pointer".

Comment: Cutting works here with an Aures ODP-333 printer.

Comment: Thank you. It must be the printer then.